# MS SQL join query with transposing rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have two tables,
test1

```
id  name    number
1   abc     12
2   xyz     12
3   pqr     12
4   mno     3
5   hij     1
```

and

test2

```
id      displayorder        date
1       1               date example 1
1       2               date example 2
1       3               date example 3
2       1               date example 4
2       2               date example 5
2       4               date example 6
3       1               date example 7
3       2               date example 8
4       1               date example 9
```

wanted an output of something like this
[image]

tried joins with groupby but when that query is run on the actual table (not test1 and test2, the real tables) is taking too long to execute, is there any quick and faster way to get the desired output?

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you are running.  Also provide sizing information about the tables and list any indexes defined on the tables.  An execution plan is also helpful.

Comment: Will there be always four display order? Or it's dynamic?

Comment: There will always be 4

Comment: edited to add formatted data instead of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table test1(id int,name varchar(50),  number int);
 insert into test1 values(1   ,'abc',     12);
 insert into test1 values(2   ,'xyz',     12);
 insert into test1 values(3   ,'pqr',     12);
 insert into test1 values(4   ,'mno',     3);
 insert into test1 values(5   ,'hij',     1);

 create table test2(id int,displayorder int, date varchar(50));
 insert into test2 values(1,       1,               'date example 1');
 insert into test2 values(1,       2,               'date example 2');
 insert into test2 values(1,       3,               'date example 3');
 insert into test2 values(2,       1,               'date example 4');
 insert into test2 values(2,       2,               'date example 5');
 insert into test2 values(2,       4,               'date example 6');
 insert into test2 values(3,       1,               'date example 7');
 insert into test2 values(3,       2,               'date example 8');
 insert into test2 values(4,       1,               'date example 9');
```

Query#1 (using group by and aggregation):

```
 select t.id,t.name,t.number,  max(case when displayorder=1 then date end)date1,
 max(case when displayorder=2 then date end)date2,
 max(case when displayorder=3 then date end)date3,
 max(case when displayorder=4 then date end)stage4
 from test1 t left join test2 t2 on t.id=t2.id
 group by t.id,t.name,t.number
 GO
```

Output:

| id | name | number | date1 | date2 | date3 | stage4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 12 | date example 1 | date example 2 | date example 3 | <emnull</em |
| 2 | xyz | 12 | date example 4 | date example 5 | <emnull</em | date example 6 |
| 3 | pqr | 12 | date example 7 | date example 8 | <emnull</em | <emnull</em |
| 4 | mno | 3 | date example 9 | <emnull</em | <emnull</em | <emnull</em |
| 5 | hij | 1 | <emnull</em | <emnull</em | <emnull</em | <emnull</em |

Query#2 (using pivot):

```
 select id,name,number,[1] Date1,[2] Date2,[3] Date3,[4]Stage4
 from
 (
    select t.id,t.name,t.number, displayorder, [date]
    from test1 t left join test2 t2 on t.id=t2.id
 ) t
 pivot
 (
 max([date]) for displayorder in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
 )piv
```

Output:

| id | name | number | Date2 | Date2 | Date3 | Stage4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 12 | date example 1 | date example 2 | date example 3 | <emnull</em |
| 2 | xyz | 12 | date example 4 | date example 5 | <emnull</em | date example 6 |
| 3 | pqr | 12 | date example 7 | date example 8 | <emnull</em | <emnull</em |
| 4 | mno | 3 | date example 9 | <emnull</em | <emnull</em | <emnull</em |
| 5 | hij | 1 | <emnull</em | <emnull</em | <emnull</em | <emnull</em |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e4538dbe97a027b2260416aa7d1b184)*

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface.

Comment: You are most welcome. If this answer solved your problem then please accept it. Best wishes